# Image Slider with Images from Database

Tags: asp.net, image, slider

I am searching a simple Image Slider for 3 to 5 images for ASP.Net.
I know there are hundrets of this, but I search something which I can easily load the filenames from database while loading the page.

It should look like this on www.urepair.de

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Easy slider](http://cssglobe.com/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider/). Bind the data using a repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptrSlider" OnItemDataBound="rptrSlider_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <a href="<%# Eval("YourNavigateUrl") %>">
                <asp:Image ID="imgSliderItem" runat="server" />
            </a>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

In your C# code use the ItemDataBound event:

```
protected void rptrSlider_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            YourSliderItem sliderItem = (YourSliderItem)e.Item.DataItem;
            Image imgSliderItem = e.Item.FindControl("imgSliderItem") as Image;
            imgSliderItem.AlternateText = sliderItem.AltText;
            imgSliderItem.ImageUrl = sliderItem.ImgUrl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I had but how to insert the .png files from database?